# react native push notification that can be removed after button click

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications

I am using react native v0.45.1.
How can I add to my application notification (no matter if the app is in the background or foreground) that the user can remove only after click an acknowledge button.
I don't want the user to swipe the notification aside without notice it.

how can it be done?
I am not sure https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications will do what I need.

**Edit**

I want to have a notification that will act like:
 '**USB debugging connected**
 'Touch to disable USB debugging'

The notification can't be removed unless the user actively do something, in my case it will be 'click' on a button

Comment: why you are not sure? It looks like the link you provided is your solution

Comment: if you are referring interactive Notifications: 
"Interactive notifications allow you to reply to a message right from the notification banner or take action right from the lock screen." - I am looking for notification that can't be ignore with a "normal" swipe, but an active user action like clicking on 'acknowledge button".

Comment: I also found this package 'https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification' but I still can't understand if the actions property (that if available for iOS and Android)  will "prevent" the user to swipe the notification. any one can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after a lot of digging the solution I implemented was:

1. setting repeat interval for the notification.
   for android:
   repeatType: 'time',
   repeatTime: timeSpan,

for iOS:
    repeatType: 'minute',

2. when the user click the notification (decided its not the right approached to add actions - buttons - to notification):

   ```
   PushNotification.configure({
       onNotification: (notification) => {
           console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
           const clicked = notification.userInteraction;

           if (clicked) {
               if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
                   PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: notification.data.id });
               } else {
                   PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: notification.id });
               }
           }
       },
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this might not be the exact answer to this question. However,
I was looking for a similar solution earlier; how to remove notifications that hasn't been dismissed or opened by a user.

Sometimes the user might open the application / screen, without clicking on the notification. The notification will still be displayed in that case.

Using React Native with **Expo**, this is the solution I created for removing old notifications created using their Push Notification API.

```
import * as Notifications from "expo-notifications";
//...

// Remove notifications that exists for this conversation!
useEffect(() => {

    Notifications.getPresentedNotificationsAsync().then(res => {
        for (let k in res) {
            if (
                res[k].request.content.data &&
                res[k].request.content.data.screen === "Conversations" &&
                res[k].request.content.data.conversationId === conversationId
            ) {

                Notifications.dismissNotificationAsync(res[k].request.identifier);

                console.log("removed a notification for this conversation");
            }
        }

    });
}, []);
```

By using the data sent to the Push Notification API, we can determine which notifications should be removed. in this case all notifications containing a conversationId matching the current value from the route are dismissed.